# Vista web site connection problem

Tags: windows-vista, website, connection

I set up a website in a new computer running Vista Home Premium.  The website works fine when you call //localhost/ from IE Explorer.  However, you can't open the site from another computer.  The router is definitely set to pass port 80 requests on to this machine; in fact, the website was working perfectly well on a Windows XP machine which was replaced by this computer.

You cannot even ping the ip address from another computer.

How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Are you trying to access this internally (from inside your network) or externally (from outside your network)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest double checking the ip address on the "server" and making sure it is set to a static ip address outside the range being used for DHCP by your router. Then if that's not working try forwarding a different external port to port 80 on the internal server say 32323 and then navigating to `http://externalip:32323/` and see if that works on the off chance your ISP is blocking port 80 traffic.``

Answer (score 1):

Are both machines on the same LAN? Are you trying to reach the client by name or IP address (not using localhost, right?)?
If by name, what do you have configured to handle name resolution? Can you ping the web server by name from the server?

I have more questions :-) But perhaps more info would help first.

Comment: I am working with both a LAN client and a remote client.  From the remote client, I cannot ping the ip address (it's a static ip) or open the website.  From the LAN client I can ping the server by name but not by ip address.  I tried putting the server name (//charlotte/) into IE on the LAN client, but that doesn't open the web site either.

Comment: That's strange, are you sure the server hasn't been reallocated a new ip.  I could understand being able to ping ip but not name but the other way round sound's like you have the ip address wrong.  Which probably means you have port 80 being forwarded to the wrong address on the router.

Comment: *#!#%$!! @Col, you were right - the ip address was wrong.  I'm working remotely, and I guess that when the machine was reinstalled the part time IT guy (AKA the company owner) assigned the wrong ip address.  All is working now, thank you to all who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is to check the Windows Firewall settings on the "server" box.

Step 2 is to make sure you have the web site configured for port 80 (if you have more than one site, IIS defaults to other ports)

Step 3 is to wait until this gets auto-migrated to ServerFault.com in case those first two steps don't work out.

Comment: Thanks, but the first 2 steps are not the problem; Windows Firewall is deactivated, and the site is set for port 80. I wondered whether I should have asked this on ServerFault :)